# Splitting OSM data into layers by tags (QGIS modeler)

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-modeler, quickosm

I have a problem with using the QGIS modeler to split a downloaded .osm file into layers. What I am trying to achieve is a structure like this:

- Traffic (lines)

  - Main Roads
  - Roads
  - Small Roads
- Natural (polygons)

  - Farmland
  - Forest
- Symbols (points)

  - Church
  - School

... as well as applying a predefined .qml style to each layer.

What I have tried: I've tried installing the QuickOSM plugin and using its functions in the QGIS modeler. I wanted to split the (offline) OSM file into layers (with attributes for further processing) (see image):

[image]

What I get when executing this (simple) command is this:

> An error has occured while executing Python code:
>
> TypeError: cannot deepcopy this pattern object
>
> Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
>
> QGIS version: 2.12.2-Lyon Lyon, b403532

Am I doing something wrong using the QGIS modeler? To me this operation seems logical: Take the OSM file and split it into points, polygons, multipolygons and lines.

Is there a workaround for this bug?

I have submitted a bug report (https://github.com/3liz/QuickOSM/issues/78), but in the meantime I thought of using a SpatiaLite DB as a solution. Now my question is:

- How can I create layers from queries to the SpatiaLite DB inside the QGIS modeler? I know SQL, but which tables should I look at (I need the tags as well as the geometry) and which algorithm should I use? (I do not know what every QGIS algorithm does, this is why I tried the QuickOSM plugin, since it should do exactly this for me)

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange. Please not that the format of this Q&A site requires us to stick to one question per thread. Please edit your post to focus on one question only. Feel free to post any additional question in additional threads.

Comment: @underdark : edited. My question is how to load the OSM data into layers (whether it be via a plugin, DB or some other workaround).